# ASP y MySQL remoto

Tags: mysql, asp

Por X motivo debo realizar una conexión desde ASP (clásico) alojado en el servidor 1 (windows) a MySQL alojado en un servidor 2 (linux), tengo instalado el driver y realiza la conexión, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Access denied for user
>   'user'@'ipservidor1' (using password: YES)

El problema es que el string de conexión tiene la IP del servidor 1 y no la del servidor 2 y cuando agrego la IP del servidor 2 me arroja el siguiente error:

> [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Access denied for user
>   'user@ipservidor2'@'ipservidor1' (using password: YES)

Saben que puede estar ocurriendo? Gracias.

Comment: El mensaje de error parece indicar que lo está mal es o el nombre de usuario o la contraseña que estás usando: `Access denied`... `Acceso denegado`, indica que ese usuario no existe o que la contraseña es incorrecta.

Comment: ¿Revisastes que estén abiertos los puertos necesarios en el firewall? ¿Configuraste el acceso externo en el archivo my.cnf de Mysql?

Comment: El usuario y la clave existe, el problema es que se intenta conectar al usuario user@ipservidor2'@'ipservidor1 y debería ser user@ipservidor2, voy a revisar el archivo my.cnf ya que el firewall ya se modifico para que acpte la conexión. Gracias